# How to not equal multiple table mysql

Tags: mysql

Table_Teacher

```
id    | name  
-----------------  
1     | Kevin  
2     | Alex   
3     | jax   
4     | Albert
```

Table_Supervisor

```
id    | id_teacher  
-----------------   
1     | 1  
2     | 3
```

I want to display 2 data (Alex & Albert) in  table_teacher
with queries

```
SELECT A.name FROM table_teacher A,tbl_supervisor B WHERE  B.id_teacher != A.id;
```

why is this not working ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`, which might perform better than subqueries.

```
select t.name
from Teacher t 
left join Supervisor s on t.id=s.id_teacher
where s.id_teacher is null;
```

Above query will get only the values which are on Teacher  table but not on Supervisor  table

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98ae9aa420456e69bae05f00ec34eb43

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways.

A simple one is to use a subquery to get all teachers that are not contained in the subquery of supervisor

```
SELECT A.name FROM table_teacher a where a.id not in 
      (select b.id_teacher from table_supervisor b WHERE b.id_teacher = a.id);
```

Comment: oke thankss , I will try it